# Having issues pausing the setInterval and then continuing

Tags: javascript, html

I have run into a little issue with a timer clock I was building. All went well but in short this is what it does:

1. user gets to set the time he/she wants to study or do any activity for
2. user presses start
3. the start button changes to a "stop" button
4. the timer counts down from the time chosen by the user
5. once the timer hits 0 the clock with stop and button changes back to "start" and everything is reset to 0:00

**Note**

Once the user taps the start button or the start button the device will vibrate if capable to notify the user.

---

**The Issue**

The problem I have is that when the clock is running and the user presses the "Stop Study" button, then the clock stops, yes thats good but when he/she presses the button again (which now should be a "start" button because its essentially paused), then the clock takes the time that was given and starts the clock over from that time the user gave and not continue until 0:00.

I have check out a few articles and I have used variables and switched between the Boolean state and checked if the clock is running or not.

```
isRunning = !isRunning
```

I have seen a few say that I should use:

```
clearInterval(name);
```

This doesn't work because I dont want to clear the state of the clock or maybe I am doing it wrong.

---

**Code**

The link to a fiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/ToreanJoel/c75vLf8b/

---

**HTML**

```
<br/>
<div class="timer" id="startingTimer">
    <p class="title" id="state">Break</p>
    <p id="time">00:00</p><span ng-style="{'height':fillHeight, 'background':fillColor }" class="fill" style="height: 0.933333%; background: rgb(153, 204, 0);"></span>

</div>
<br/>
<div class="session" id="toggleSessionStart">
    <div class="timer control startingTimercontroller" id="startingTimercontroller">
        <p class="title controlTitle" id="StartTimer">Start Study</p>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="timer control startingPauseTimercontroller" id="startingPauseTimercontroller">
        <p class="title controlTitle" id="StartPauseTimer">Start Break</p>
    </div>--></div>
<br/>
<header>
    <div class="session">
        <div class="sessionCtrl">
            <p>session length</p>
            <input type="number" class="time" id="valueTimerSession" value="10">
        </div>
        <!--<div class="breakCtrl">
            <p>break length</p>
            <input type="number" class="time" id="valueTimerBreak" value="5"> 
       </div>--></div>
</header>
```

---

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #333333;
    color: #fff;
}
#time {
    font-size: 90px;
    position: relative;
    top: -40px;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    #time {
        font-size: 90px;
        position: relative;
        top: -80px;
    }
}
.plus {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2em;
    outline: none;
}
.time {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
.minus {
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2em;
    outline: none;
}
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 20px;
}
.session .breakCtrl, .session .sessionCtrl {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
.session {
    font-size: .8em;
    display: flex;
}
.timer {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    font-size: 4em;
    border: 2px solid #99CC00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.control {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    font-size: 4em;
    border: 2px solid #99CC00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.startingTimercontroller {
    background: #37B703 !important;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.startingPauseTimercontroller {
    background: #B70000 !important;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
.title {
    margin: 45px;
    margin-bottom: -30px;
}
.controlTitle {
    font-size: 28px;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    margin: 0;
}
.heading {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

---

**JS**

```
//event Listener
var clickStart = document.getElementById("toggleSessionStart");

//pauseing the clock
var clockRunning = false;
var clicked = false;

//getting the user value ammount to study and break for
var valueTimerSession = parseInt(document.getElementById('valueTimerSession').value);


function pomodoro(studyTime) {
    this.studyTime = studyTime;
    this.seconds = 59;
    this.timerDOM = document.getElementById("time");
    this.state = document.getElementById("state");
    this.toggleSessionStart = document.getElementById('toggleSessionStart');
}

pomodoro.prototype.startStudyTicker = function () {
    var thisStudyTicker = this;
    var seconds = this.seconds - 1;
    var DOM = this.timerDOM;
    var minutes = this.studyTime - 1;
    var loopingSeconds = seconds;
    var state = this.state;
    var toggleSessionStart = this.toggleSessionStart;

    if (clicked && clockRunning) {
        console.log('We are runnung');
        window.ticker = setInterval(function () {
            //save the minutes to global variable
            window.minSaved = minutes;
            window.secSaved = loopingSeconds;

            console.log("The time saved is " + window.minSaved + ":" + window.secSaved);

            console.log(minutes + ":" + loopingSeconds);
            var tick = loopingSeconds--;
            if (loopingSeconds >= 0) {

                tick;
                DOM.innerHTML = minutes.toString() + ":" + (loopingSeconds < 10 ? '0' + loopingSeconds.toString() : loopingSeconds.toString());

            } else {
                if (minutes > 0) {
                    minutes--;
                    loopingSeconds = seconds;
                    tick;
                    DOM.innerHTML = minutes.toString() + ":" + (loopingSeconds < 10 ? '0' + loopingSeconds.toString() : loopingSeconds.toString());
                }
                if (minutes <= 0) {
                    //vibrate - Timer is Done
                    window.navigator.vibrate(300);
                    console.log('im finished');
                    clearInterval(ticker);
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        if (!clicked && !clockRunning) {
            clearInterval(ticker);
        }
    }

}

pomodoro.prototype.stopStudyTicker = function () {
    var thisStudyTickerStop = this;
    console.log('We are paused');

    clearInterval(ticker);
    thisStudyTickerStop.startStudyTicker();
}

//get the session title
var sessionTitle = document.getElementById('state');

//the DOM toggle
function toggleDOM(chosenTime) {
    if (clicked && clockRunning) {
        //started the session - the Title
        sessionTitle.innerHTML = "Session";
        clickStart.innerHTML =
            '<div class="timer control startingPauseTimercontroller" id="startingPauseTimercontroller"><p class="title controlTitle" id="StartTimer">Stop Study</p></div>';

        //vibrate
        window.navigator.vibrate(300);

        //prototype execution
        var startStudy = new pomodoro(chosenTime);
        startStudy.startStudyTicker();
    } else {
        sessionTitle.innerHTML = "Break";
        clickStart.innerHTML =
            '<div class="timer control startingTimercontroller" id="startingTimercontroller"><p class="title controlTitle" id="StartTimer">Start Study</p></div>';

        //vibrate
        window.navigator.vibrate([100, 100, 100]);

        //prototype execution
        var stopStudy = new pomodoro();
        stopStudy.stopStudyTicker();
    }
}

clickStart.addEventListener('click', function () {
    //user clicked and the clock starts
    clicked = !clicked;
    clockRunning = !clockRunning;

    //valueTimerBreak = parseInt(document.getElementById('valueTimerBreak').value);
    valueTimerSession = parseInt(document.getElementById('valueTimerSession').value);

    //the Toggle
    toggleDOM(valueTimerSession);

});
```

---

I was looking at a few things on stack overflow but nothing really seemed to help as im not trying to use multiple buttons to pause or play but use one that toggles its states and the markup and the layout can be seen on jsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/ToreanJoel/c75vLf8b/).

---

I'm using Prototypal Pattern and I'm not use to it yet but I will be going over everything again just to refactor the code anyway to get use to it.

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't really understood your code but I made my own, basically if you click on a button and the seconds aren't stored in a variable - store them, else just continue looping. I think you'll understand my code, just replace your javascript with my.

```
var clickStart = document.getElementById("toggleSessionStart");

var pomodoro = function() {
    this.inProgress = false;
    this.studyTime = null;
    this.timerInstance = null;
    this.timerDOM = document.getElementById("time");
    this.stateElement = document.getElementById("state");
    this.toggleSessionStart = document.getElementById('toggleSessionStart');
}

pomodoro.prototype = {
    start: function() {
        var parent = this;

        if(this.studyTime === null) this.studyTime = parseInt(document.getElementById('valueTimerSession').value, 10) * 60;

        this.timerInstance = setInterval(function() {
            parent.studyTime--;

            if(parent.studyTime < 1) parent.destroy();
            else parent.updateTime();
        }, 1000);

        return this;
    },
    pause: function() {
        clearInterval(this.timerInstance);
        this.timerInstance = null;

        return this;
    },
    destroy: function() {
        this.pause();
        this.studyTime = null;
        this.toogleState(false);
        this.timerDOM.innerHTML = '00:00';
        return this;
    },
    updateTime: function() {
        var totalSec = this.studyTime,
              minutes = Math.floor(totalSec / 60),
              seconds = totalSec % 60;

        this.timerDOM.innerHTML = (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
        return this;
    },
    toogleState: function(state) {
        this.inProgress = (typeof state !== 'undefined') ? state : !this.inProgress;

        if(this.inProgress) {
            this.stateElement.innerHTML = "Session";
            clickStart.innerHTML = '<div class="timer control startingPauseTimercontroller" id="startingPauseTimercontroller"><p class="title controlTitle" id="StartTimer">Stop Study</p></div>';
            this.start();
        }
        else {
            this.stateElement.innerHTML = "Break";
            clickStart.innerHTML = '<div class="timer control startingTimercontroller" id="startingTimercontroller"><p class="title controlTitle" id="StartTimer">Start Study</p></div>';
            this.pause();
        }

        window.navigator.vibrate(300);

        return this;
    }
};

var pomodoroInstance = new pomodoro();

clickStart.addEventListener('click', function () {
    pomodoroInstance.toogleState();
});
```

BTW. there is one problem, you can't stop the timer manually so if user wants to set different time he will have to reload the page. You can add a little button which will trigger `destroy()` method.

Comment: I never had time to look at the code yesterday and today i just went through to understand what you did. i like how this is also clean and easy to read. i see what i could have done. thanks man

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather implement the logic for the clock in a separate class, after all a clock doesn't need anything but a time, our api will consist on methods to start/stop/pause the timer

The gui then creates a clock instance, whenever you click the start/stop button we just need to call the magic clock methods that control the timer, note that the clock doesn't have a method to render itself, it'd be better to have another class like `ClockGUI` that has an inner instance of `Clock`, this new class would just call methods of the `Clock` instance to update the timer and also update the gui

```js
function Clock (time) {
  this.timeLeft = time
  this.paused = false
}

Clock.prototype.start = function () {
  this.raf = requestAnimationFrame(
    this._loop.bind(this)
  )
}

Clock.prototype.stop = function () {
  cancelRequestAnimationFrame(this.raf)
}

Clock.prototype.togglePause = function () {
  this.paused = !this.paused
}

Clock.prototype._update = function (t) {
  if (!this.paused) {
    this.timeLeft -= t
    if (this.timeLeft <= 0) {
      this.stop()
    }
  }
}

Clock.prototype._loop = function () {
  this.raf = requestAnimationFrame(this._loop.bind(this))
  var now = Date.now()
  var delta = now - (this.prev || now)
  this._update(delta)
  this.prev = now
}


// game
var timeLeft = document.querySelector('#time-left')
var input = document.querySelector('input')
var button = document.querySelector('button')
var started = false
var clock
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  button.innerText = button.innerText === 'start' ? 'pause' : 'start'

  if (!started) {
    started = true
    clock = new Clock(input.value * 1000 * 60)
    clock.start()
    
    input.disabled = true
    
    return
  }
  
  // toggle the state of the clock
  clock.togglePause()
})

function render () {
  requestAnimationFrame(render)
  // render only if a clock was created
  if (clock) {
    var time = Math.floor(clock.timeLeft / 1000)
    var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
    var seconds = time % 60
    var ms = clock.timeLeft % 1000
    timeLeft.innerHTML = minutes + ':' + seconds + ':' + ms
  }
}

requestAnimationFrame(render)
```

```html
<div>
  Time left: <span id="time-left"></span>
</div>

<button> start </button>
  
<input type="number" value="10">
```

As you've seen the clock is not controlled by `setInterval` but by `requestAnimationFrame`, the problem of having a fixed 1000 ms interval is the pause behavior you want:

- pause: just call `clearInterval`
- start: compute how much time is left that isn't part of a second e.g. `timeLeft % 1000`, set a timeout on that much time left and then call set interval again

You could use `setInterval` with a small frequency like 10ms, however it's not guaranteed that the function will be called with exactly 10ms but **as close as** 10ms therefore you still need to compute the time elapsed between two calls of the `setInterval` function, in the example above this is done on `Clock.prototype._loop`